# How to write a regex to look for NOT string1 AND NOT string2?

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression to to return a positive match if two strings are NOT in tested string. For example,

```
^((?!string1).)*$
```

will match if `string1` is not contained in the tested string. How can I write this to test if a string does not contain `string1` AND does not contain `string2`?

Answer (score 4):

You are nearly there:

```
^((?!string1|string2).)*$
```

You can use `|` character as an OR in the negative lookahead so that it will fail if either string is matched.

Note that you could also rewrite this particular example like this:

```
^((?!string[12]).)*$
```

My assumption is that your actual use case won't be as trivial, so using `|` is the more generic solution.

Comment: both string1 and string2 have to be the same length, though

Comment: it's an issue if string1 and string2 don't have the same length, as it won't work in this case

Comment: That restriction is only true for lookbehinds, not lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even need regular expressions for that, functions like "index of substring" certainly exist in the language you're working on.

If you really need regex for the matches, don't over-engineer it and use your language features:

```
if (!(str =~ /regex/) && !(str =~ /regex/))
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would to use the `(?!)` as a lookaround. Something like this:

```
^(?!.*string1)(?!.*string2).*$
```